# Calendar event mail to attendee from iCloud is not coming

Tags: icalendar, caldav, dday

```
IList<IAttendee> icalAttendess = new List<IAttendee>();
    IAttendee icalAttendee = new DDay.iCal.Attendee("MAILTO:abc@domain.com")
    {
        CommonName = attendees.Name.Decode(),
        Role = "REQ-PARTICIPANT",
        ParticipationStatus = ParticipationStatus.Accepted
    };
    icalAttendess.Add(icalAttendee);
```

Here, I am creating attendee list which is added to the event. I am using CalDav extension using DDay.ical to create event on icloud. Attendees are added to event correctly but problem is no calendar event mail from iCloud is being sent to attendee(mail having accept, decline, maybe option). Mails are sent in past but suddenly mails are not coming from iCloud. I have also set RSVP to true but no joy. If I create appointment directly on iCloud.com and add attendee then mail is coming to attendee. Any idea? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the problem is CalDav, not dday. That said, don't use dday. Use iCal.net instead: it actually has support, bugfixes, and performance enhancements. It also has a real software license. http://rianjs.net/2016/07/dday-ical-is-now-ical-net

Comment: Thanks!
I have checked https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/wiki/Migrating-from-dday.ical
Wiil revert once I am done with this.
Do we have any documentation for implementation?

Comment: Is ical.net freely available?

Comment: Thanks! received calendar invite mail.

Comment: Hi rianjs,
    I came across with a problem while fetching events from iCloud. Problem is that the event that are directly created on iCloud are not getting parsed using ical.net. While that are being parsed by dday.ical.
Event created using ical.net are parsed correctly.
IICalendarCollection calendars = Calendar.LoadFromStream(stream, Encoding.UTF8); At this line error comes as date time is not in correct format.
For directly created event dtStart comes as DTSTART;X-VOBJ-ORIGINAL-TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20170118T120000Z.

Comment: For event I created via ical.net I set timezone as UTC. And while fetching dtStart comes as DTSTART:20170118T120000Z and it is parsed correctly.
Dday working fine if I use dday same event gets parsed-:
IICalendarCollection calendars = iCalendar.LoadFromStream(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: Ical.Net -:
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(calDataNode.SelectSingleNode("./*[local-name()='propstat']/*[local-name()='prop']/*[local-name()='calendar-data']").InnerText;
IICalendarCollection calendars = Calendar.LoadFromStream(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
Dday.iCal -: 
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(calDataNode.SelectSingleNode("./*[local-name()='propstat']/*[local-name()='prop']/*[local-name()='calendar-data']").InnerText;
IICalendarCollection calendars = iCalendar.LoadFromStream(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: Exception Message -: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Yes, ical.net is licensed with the MIT license, and available as a nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net -- ask your ical.net specific question as a new question, and tag it with "icaldotnet". Comment threads aren't for new questions.